# Setting image in the view after downloading from web with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, json.net

Let's say I have 3 image views in my xaml . I am downloading images from a server & now I want to set those images  in my image views  . How can I do that ? Please Help ! 
My Code :

```
   void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //parse data
            var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(e.Result);

            //load into list
            for (int i = 0; i < container.MyBookList.Count; i++)
            {
                newData[i] = new data();
                newData[i].id = container.MyBookList[i].ID;
                newData[i].title = container.MyBookList[i].TITLE;
                newData[i].type = container.MyBookList[i].TYPE;
                newData[i].price = container.MyBookList[i].PRICE;
                newData[i].downloadLink = container.MyBookList[i].DOWNLOADLINK;
                string file_name = newData[i].downloadLink.ToString();
                string image_uri = "http://www.banglanews24.com/images/imgAll/" + file_name;   
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
                wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(image_uri), wc);
            }

    void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
        {
            try
            {   //I can set just one image here....what should I do ?

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(e.Result);
                image1.Source = image;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception handle appropriately for your app  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Either cancelled or error handle appropriately for your app  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: First, make sure OpenReadAsync is called multiple times.

Comment: OpenReadAsync is called multiple times . I am sure .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. It looks like you only have 1 image control to display multiple images. What is image1?

Comment: I have 3 image controls in my xaml to display 3 different downloaded images . image1 is the image control from xaml .

Comment: image controls are : image1 , image2 , image3 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
   void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //parse data
        var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(e.Result);

        //load into list
        for (int i = 0; i < container.MyBookList.Count; i++)
        {
            newData[i] = new data();
            newData[i].id = container.MyBookList[i].ID;
            newData[i].title = container.MyBookList[i].TITLE;
            newData[i].type = container.MyBookList[i].TYPE;
            newData[i].price = container.MyBookList[i].PRICE;
            newData[i].downloadLink = container.MyBookList[i].DOWNLOADLINK;
            string file_name = newData[i].downloadLink.ToString();
            string image_uri = "http://www.banglanews24.com/images/imgAll/" + file_name;   

            Uri uri = new Uri(image_uri, UriKind.Relative);
            ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);

            if (i==0) image1.source = imgSource;
            else if (i==1) image2.source = imgSource;
            else if (i==2) image3.source = imgSource;
            etc
        }
```

You will find that your images will automatically be downloaded when you give it a Image URI.

Comment: image1.source = image_uri gives an error .
"Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' "